# AngularJS: Call httpget on value change from textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web service which returns json file on call with a parameter for the id of an entry. I have a angular method that returns the data returned from that method. I have no idea how to recall the service when the input of the id has changed as I want to recall that method when a new value has been supplied.

The parameter that I pass in for the Id is called Reference. The HTML returns object with a reference of 1234 but if I change the value I dont know how to recall the service.

This is what I have so far:

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", [])
.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
    var res = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'AirPortrWebService.asmx/DashboardDetail',
        params: { Reference : '1234' }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.booking = response.data
    });
    $scope.test = "Angular Method Called";
    $scope.Reference = '1234';

});
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/NewAppTwo.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
    {{test}}
    {{Reference}}
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="Reference" ng-change="booking"/>

    {{booking}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change ng-change="booking" to a function that is called everytime that models Refences changes:

```
$scope.getReference = function(referenceNumber){
  $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'AirPortrWebService.asmx/DashboardDetail',
         params: { Reference :  referenceNumber}
  }).function (response) {
     $scope.booking = response.data
  });
}

<input type="text" ng-model="Reference" ng-change="getReference(Reference)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", [])
.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.refresh = function(){
        var res = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'AirPortrWebService.asmx/DashboardDetail',
            params: { Reference : $scope.Reference }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.booking = response.data
        });
    }
    $scope.test = "Angular Method Called";
    $scope.Reference = '1234';

});
```

and html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Reference" ng-change="refresh()"/>
```

ng-change call the given function each time the input change.
`refresh()` don't need a parameter because it use `$scope.Reference`

Comment: Need to change params: { Reference : '1234' } to params: { Reference : $scope.Reference }